# How to make colordialog appear?

Tags: c#, colordialog

I am simply trying to make a colordialog appear, using the following code as a test out/practise assignment.

```
{
            Point puntA = new Point(10, 300);
            Point puntB = new Point(90, 200);
         
            Pen tekenpotlood = new Pen(colorDialog1.Color , 4);

            Graphics papier = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

            papier.DrawLine(tekenpotlood, puntA, puntB);

}
```

I have dragged a colordialog onto the form, I have also added the code menntioned in the textbook (with or without erasing colordialog)

any help is appreaciated with this problem..

Comment: see: [Learn Microsoft.com: ColorDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.colordialog?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer, Classes is the next chapter of the course, but i got it to work, with some changes.

here is the code now functioning:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ColorDialog colorDialog;

    public Form1()
    {
        colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       





    Pen pen = new Pen(colorDialog.Color, 4);
    Point puntA = new Point(10, 300);
    Point puntB = new Point(90, 200);
    
    if (colorDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       

    Graphics papier = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

    papier.DrawLine(pen, puntA, puntB);
    }

        else
        {
            // The user cancelled the dialog
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: For quick testing, `pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();` is okay, but is almost never the correct approach as the drawing will disappear when the window is repainted (minimize the form and restore it to see this happen).  Instead, wire up the `Paint()` event of the PictureBox and use the supplied `e.Graphics` in that event.